# Написать алгоритм со временем выполнения O(n)

Tags: алгоритм

Есть вот такое задание

Массив А[1, …, n] будет называться d-отсортированным (для d ≤ n) если каждый ключ в массиве находиться на расстоянии не более чем d от его места в массиве А в котором он будет отсортирован. Нужно сделать алгоритм который сортирует d-отсортированным массив размером n и сортирует его.

и вот такой вопрос

> напишите алгоритм у которого время выполнения в самом плохом случае O(n) если d постоянная.

Какой это может быть алгоритм?

Comment: `сортирует d-отсортированным массив размером n и сортирует его.` - что это вообще значит? Отсортировать d-сортированный массив или сделать из заданного массива d-сортированный?

Comment: Если d=1, то получается массив просто отсортирован, значит для данной ситуации надо использовать обычные алгоритмы сортировки... А разве есть такие, которые удовлетворяют O(n)? Надо наверное как-т ограничить значение d, например d >= n/2.

Comment: Судя по требованиям... ближе всего к такому алгоритму - это алгоритм сортировки Шенона... просто надо в какой-то момент (тут надо понять в какой именно) надо прекратить его итерации. И да d таки надо как-то ограничивать (тут тоже надо пукумекать).

Comment: @Zugr Наверное, вы имеете в виду Шелла, не Шеннона

Comment: Учитывая уточнение Zurg мы понимаем, что мы не можем за O(N) сделать из заданного массива d-сортированный без дополнительных ограничений на d. Тогда полагаем, что вам нужно отсортировать d-сортированный массив. Это можно сделать, например, с помощью пузырькового алгоритма, запуская его не на N итераций, а на 2d (вероятно просто d, но я не стал доказывать), что при d - константе, имеет сложность O(N). Кроме сортировки пузырьком, многие другие квадратичные могут подойти, но для каждого надо отдельно смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Сортируете вставками.
Время работы для такого массива `O(d*n) = O(n)`, поскольку d - константа.

Comment: d=1. Сортируйте! Вы должны получить полностью отсортированный массив. Алгорим вставками O(n*n).

Comment: @Zugr Для такого массива сортировка вставками завершится за 2n операций.

Comment: для какого такого?
Начальные данные - массив не сортирован.
Конечные данные: d=1 (т.е. массив полностью отсортирован).
Алгоритм: метод вставок.
Результат: время работы алгоритма в среднем O(n*n).

Comment: @Zugr Видимо, мы с вами по-разному интерпретируем вопрос

Comment: Что ж я даже соглашусь с Вами... Часть вопроса действительно можно интерпретировать по разному.

Comment: Видимо вы предполагаете наличие уже частично сортированного массива, и доведение его до полностью сортированного состояния. Так?

Comment: @Zugr Да, именно так. К сожалению, автор пока не появляется, чтобы прояснить  предложение `Нужно сделать алгоритм...`

Comment: Поддерживаю @MBo. Сортировка вставками имеет сложность O(dn). Иногда d может быть близок к n. Тогда это квадратичный алгоритм. Но если d = const, то это вполне себе линейный алгоритм. Многие реализации qsort получают приблизительно отсортированный массив (d=16 или 32) и запускают сортировку вставками в качестве последнего шага.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, только сортировку вставками в качестве последнего шага используют не из-за частичной упорядоченности, а из-за того, что код такой сортировки получается намного короче кода основного алгоритма и при малых N, не взирая на квадратичную сложность, работает быстрее

Comment: @avp, сперва рекурсивный qsort выполняет сортировку пока длина подмассива больше шестнадцати. Когда все рекурсивные вызовы завершились, запускается сортировка вставками **на всём массиве сразу**. Так быстрее.

Comment: Прочитайте этот комментарий: [qsort.c:197](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html#197).

Comment: Ещё один пример: [stl_algo.h:5207](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01347.html#l05207). В теле функции два вызова: `introsort` (который в душе почти `quicksort`) и затем `insertion_sort` **на полном контейнере**.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, очень интересный подход, спасибо. Даже жаль, что уже нет желания вернуться к измерениям сортировок...

Comment: Когда я у Седжвика прочитал про такой метод, были сомнения, погонял тесты. Quicksort и Mergesort при использовании вставок процентов на 5-10 быстрее работают. Использование вставок на квиксорте хоть на полном массиве, хоть на мелких - практической разницы не увидел. Ещё интересно, что на разных компьютерах Heapsort мог быть как быстрее Merge, так и медленнее - видимо, работа с памятью влияет (локальность данных и т.п.)